# Lucas Kanade Optical Flow

Tags: opencv

I would like to draw a bounding box based on all the points I got from the output of cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK.
I had done the tracking of the object and able to draw lines showing the direction of flow. However, I am having problem in grouping all the points up and categorized as an object.

I am doing a multiple object tracking project which the object I am tracking is vehicles on the road.
Any suggestions on how the bounding box could be drawn so that only related object is being drawn as cars?

Thank you
[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

Following you can try...

1. Since your targets are moving you can do a frame differentiation `(diffFrame = currentFrame - prevsFrame )` to find out the areas which have gone under change compared to its previous frame, hence take only those points(already detected by opticalflow) which lie on the the changed areas.
2. Use some clustering technique like a K-means clustering to group the points..
3. Once you have group the points find the minimum x coordinate,minimum y coordinate,maximum x coordinate and maximum y coordinate. draw a reactangular box of `(Xmin,Ymin,(Xmax-Xmin+1),(Ymax-Ymin+1))` which is `(Xorigin,Yorigin,Widht,Height)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to implement it in my design. If any further problem, I will let you know.

Comment: I had read and try to understand the k-means algorithm's sample provided in opencv c. However, I am not clear about the explanation for some parts like cvGetRow, cvRandArr and RNG. I had got a range of points from my Optical Flow's result. However, I am struggling in getting a way to link that to K-means clustering. Any clue for that ?

Comment: I had added some of the pictures showing where the points are.